# How to resolve 'ion-item' is not a known element in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

i am building an app with ionic, i noticed that when i want to convert my app to apk, the ionic elements like `ion-header, ion-title, ion-list etc` stops working in the modal. it works on other pages except in the modal

here is the code for comment.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import  { NgxEmojModule } from 'ngx-emoj';
import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

import { CommentPageRoutingModule } from './comment-routing.module';
import { CommentPage } from './comment.page';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxEmojModule,
    PipesModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    CommentPageRoutingModule
  ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [
    CommentPage,
        TimeAgoPipe]
})
export class CommentPageModule {}
```

I added `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in both the app module and the page module, but its not just working.

here is the comment.page.html

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title class="centerAM">{{no_comm | shortNumber}} comment{{no_comm>1?'s':''}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
....
```

I am getting this when i try to convert it to apk

```
src/app/modal/comment/comment.page.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ion-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <ion-header class="ion-no-border" *ngIf="!isLoading">
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modal/comment/comment.page.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './comment.page.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CommentPage.
src/app/modal/comment/comment.page.html:2:2 - error NG8001: 'ion-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2  <ion-toolbar>
```

here is the code where i called up the modal

```
async CommentModal(id) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: CommentPage,
        componentProps:{id},
        swipeToClose: true,
        cssClass: 'comment-modal'
    });
    await modal.present();
    return 
}
```

here is the comment.page.html page

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title class="centerAM">{{no_comm | shortNumber}} comment{{no_comm>1?'s':''}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading; else loadTemp;">
        .....
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #loadTemp>     
        <ion-item *ngFor="let comm of comms" lines="none">
            ....
        </ion-item>
    </ng-template>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ng-container *ngIf="showEm">
            ....
        </ng-container>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                .....
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid> 
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Pls what am i doing that is wrong

Comment: Have you added CommentPageModule in AppModule or in the individual page module from where you are opening the model?

Comment: i am lazy loading it

Comment: In the lazy loaded module, you need to import CommentPageModule

Comment: please share the code how exactly you are lazy loading the component. If it is a modal - modals can not be lazy loaded, they get lazy loaded together with the component importing them.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko i have updated the code

Comment: @PankajSati i have done that but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

Loading modals as part of lazy loaded pages requires the following:

1. Import CommentPageModule into your lazy loaded modal host page module
2. Ensure CommentPage is part of declarations and entryComponents array of CommentPageModule
3. Make sure there is no routing attempting to lazy load your CommentPageModule, as modals in Ionic 4+ are not lazy loaded on their own they get packaged into their hosting page module which can be lazy loaded.

The error itself means IonicModule is not available to the CommentPage modal when it’s instantiated. This means the “host” of modal (whatever page initiates modal) in its module file must have CommentPageModule imported.

Please share lazy loaded host page’s module file if you need further help.